# 'InterstitialAd' is abstract; cannot be instantiated

Tags: android, admob, interstitial, appcompatactivity

I'm updating one of my Android apps but I'm finding some problems concerning AdMob implementation (which was working well on previous versions).

This is my code:

```
public class Edition extends AppCompatActivity {

  private InterstitialAd mInterstitialAd;

  @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_edition);

        mInterstitialAd = new InterstitialAd(this); //ERROR
        mInterstitialAd.setAdUnitId(getString(R.string.full_screen_test_ad));
        mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
        mInterstitialAd.setAdListener(new AdListener() {
            @Override
            public void onAdClosed() {
                mInterstitialAd.loadAd(new AdRequest.Builder().build());
            }
        });
  }
}
```

The `initialize()` method is called during my MainActivity.

But the following error appears on the marked line:

```
'InterstitialAd' is abstract; cannot be instantiated
```

Thanks in advance for any comment you can have!

Comment: InterstitialAd is the abstract class, so you should extend it or AdManagerInterstitialAd

Comment: also, read here https://developers.google.com/admob/android/interstitial